# Python - Closeness of two values on a logarithmic scale

Tags: python, math

I have two, time value series (using pandas) and would like to represent the "closeness" of the last value in each series in regards to each other on a logarithmic scale between 0 and 1. 0 being very far away and 1 being the same.

I am not sure how to approach this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "0 being very far away". How far is "very far"? You're trying to define an absolute scale based on something that's infinite.

Comment: Asked another way, can you provide some examples that you'd expect would output a "closeness value" of 0 (and other expected values)?

Comment: For clarification. I have a historical share price and a moving average on a graph. I would like to know when these two lines "get close". I have made some progress by determining the max and min values of the share price and then to determine the max deviation (max - min). Then I use the formula: closeness = 1 - (difference / max_deviation). This is however still on a linear scale and I haven't used logs in ages.

Comment: We could devise a scale that gives 1 for the same and gets closer and closer to 0 for farther away, with 0 only reached for "infinitely far away." This avoids the problem of not knowing your values in advance, but this would not be a "logarithmic scale." Did you really mean what I wrote rather than "logarithmic"?

Comment: It does not have to perfectly logarithmic. I only mentioned it as it was the only mathematical function I know that does what I need. So for further clarification, I need the value to be 1 if they are the same, ~.9 - .8 when they are close but drop off quicker towards zero the further apart they get. Come to think of it. It doesn't actually ever need to hit zero.

Comment: Ok. Some progress. First after some manual paper calculations I realised I didn't need a logarithmic scale but an exponential scale. So the solution I have is :

Comment: Ok. Some progress. First after some manual paper calculations I realised I didn't need a logarithmic scale but an exponential scale. So the solution I have is :

linear_closeness = 1 - (difference / max_deviation)
exponential_closeness = 10^linear_closeness / 10

This is suitable for me. I am open to better solutions. Will leave the question open for a day or two and then mark it answered

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I have is :

linear_closeness = 1 - (difference / max_deviation)

exponential_closeness = 10^linear_closeness / 10

This is suitable for me. I am open to better solutions.